# Multiply previous and next elements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I've been trying to multiply the previous and next numbers in Python, but I always get a different error. This is what I've been doing:

```
u=[1, 41, 56, 80]

def Filter(vel):
    global firstDerivative 
    firstDerivative = np.repeat(None, len(vel))
    for index, obj in enumerate(vel):
       if index !=0 & index !=len(vel-1):
           firstDerivative = (vel[index-1]*vel[index+1])/2

Filter(u)
```

The folowwing Error arises:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

I actually tried map as well, but id didn't work.

Comment: Whats your data?

Comment: Give your input data !? What is your 'u' here ?

Comment: Where does numpy come into this, besides the use of `np.repeat`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it

Comment: How do you deal with None? It will throw a `ValueError` - How do you deal with zero? multiplying with zero will yield zero.

Comment: It was just an idea. I filled with Nones so I could append the elements, which was my problem.

Comment: you have None in your input!

Comment: I don't get what you mean...yes, I have None in my input.

Comment: you can't multiply None! How do you want to deal with that?

Comment: The error is in the `len(vel-1)`. `vel` is a list. Minus is not defined for that. How about `len(vel)-1`?

Comment: It looks nothing like a derivative. What do you want to calculate exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate from 1 to -1, and fill the `firstDerivative` array as you go:

```
def Filter(vel):
    global firstDerivative    # you are probably better advised to return firstDerivative instead
    firstDerivative = [0] * (len(vel) - 2)
    for ndx in range(1, len(vel) - 1):
        firstDerivative[ndx-1] = vel[ndx-1] * vel[ndx+1] / 2

firstDerivative = []        
u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Filter(u)
firstDerivative
```

#### output:

for firstderivative:

```
[1.5, 4.0, 7.5, 12.0]
```

Comment: This way I get one result. I want a list interacting with this

Comment: I tried to do that before, the same way. I get the following TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

Since `numpy` is tagged, you could simply use `a[:-2]*a[2:]/2`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a[:-2]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[2:]
array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a[:-2]*a[2:]/2
array([  1.5,   4. ,   7.5,  12. ])
```

Note that it has nothing to do with a derivative, though. You should either change your code or the variable names. A derivative would be about the difference, e.g. with `(a[i+1] - a[i])/2`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> (a[2:] - a[:-2])/2
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> np.ediff1d(a)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is the way the methodology I am using calls it. so I'm using the same names to follow it.